# How to add teechart(webchart) to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, teechart

As title,I drag WebChart in toolbox.But I can not see on web.

Visual Studio 2010 , asp.net webform.
[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deGWr.jpg) [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/821lG.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't reproduce the problem you are experiencing. We have made a simple project, with a Unicode text and the problem doesn't appear for us. Here's the project: [link](http://steema.com/files/public/WebSite1.zip).

I would suggest you check if the attached project works or not for you.
Also, I give you some indications you should keep in mind always you want show the charts in the browser working with webChart:

Note, the TempChart property may be used to select how the temporary Chart should be stored after creation and before display on the browser page. There are 4 available settings:

**Working in File:**
The File setting should be used if you wish to write temporary files to disk. By default, when TeeChart is installed, it creates registry keys with the temporary file location and equivalent virtual folder name.

**Working in Session:**
Session is a setting for temporary file storage that leaves no file on disk and removes its own cached memory files (see also the Cache and Httphandler options

**Working in Cache:**
The Cache option is very similar in setup to the Session Chart caching option. 'Cache' is a practical option to use as it uses the Cache object that belongs to the ASP.NET WebForm page and as such is easily present for most ASP.NET application configurations whereas 'Session' is susceptible to administrative limitations on some Web Servers (i.e. where administrators have chosen to disable Session support for security reasons).

**Working in Httphandler:**
The Httphandler option uses an internal TeeChart (WebChart) generator to recover the Chart image for the page. The option generates no temporary files and requires no additional aspx file to recover a Chart (as would be the case with the Session and Cache options).

You can find the more information about the above settings in the TeeChart.Net Tutorial 9. Here's the link: http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/net/tutorials/html/TeeChartProNetTutorialsContentsTutorial9-ASPNETApplications.htm

The image below shows you how can change the TempChart settings by design time:
[image]